# MacBook Pro's battery charging only to 27%

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

I have a 2017 15" MacBook Pro.

A while ago I posted question related to issues with battery here:

- [MacBook 15" (2017) - Battery Charging Problem](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/345595/macbook-15-2017-battery-charging-problem)

What's funny is that that problem solved itself eventually (The next day it charged as expected). Two weeks later I kinda got into the same problem, but now it charges only to 27%.

Interestingly, I don't have any performance problems if I am on battery and the battery usage is normal.

If someone has experienced similar problems, I am curious to know if they have done something to fix it. I have tried resetting the SMC multiple times but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Apple Support page:](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204054#notfull)

> Occasionally, the battery might not show a full charge (100%) in
>   macOS, even after the power adapter has been connected for an extended
>   period of time. The battery might appear to stop charging between 93
>   percent and 99 percent. This behavior is normal and will help to
>   prolong the overall life of the battery.

But 27% is quite low.

Additionally, you can try checking the battery cycle count. The average for your Mac is 1000.

From [this article:](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201585)

> Follow these steps to access information about your Mac notebook
>   battery, including its cycle count:
>
> Hold the Option key and click the Apple menu. Choose System
>   Information.
>
> Under the Hardware section of the System Information window, select Power. The current cycle count is listed under the Battery Information section.
>
> [image: example]